# How to mount a shared folder in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mount, share, directory

How do you you mount a shared folder in Windows Server 2008. I took these steps to create it:

Right click in Domain Controller window -> New -> Shared Folder. The UNC name (path) was "\virtual.local\share" where virtual.local is my domain controller name. Is there perhaps a problem here?

When I right-click the shared folder an option is there as "Map network drive" is this the same thing as "mounting"?

I would appreciate quick help if you have spare time.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

generally you don't need to mount a network share under windows.

you can type "\server\share" (without quotes ofc.) into the address bar of an explorer window (or use ctrl+r to get the "run command" window and enter it there). you can start programs off the share, open documents, and so on. for windows applications this is transparent, they do not need to be aware of the fact that they are accessing a network share.

if you use the share often you can map this share to a drive letter as you described in your post. it may be faster/easier to access, and you can activate the "persistent" option so it automatically reconnects in subsequent logon sessions

Comment: Thanks tkSimon, it turns out that it was to mount a shared folder using Windows (I was thinking of using AD) as it was worded wrong on the paper. All done now and thank you for answering :)